# Is there a JS library that allows one to embed external CSS in a HTML file?

Tags: javascript, web-browser, css

I'm writing a Chrome Extension. The content script pulls the HTML from the page, sends it to the background script (which sends it to a server). From either the content or background script I want to take the CSS files referenced in the HTML and embed them in the HTML itself. The CSS files don't always come from the same host (but if it makes it easier, I can accept that we can ignore CSS files from non-same-hosts).

For example with the files set up as:

`index.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="./assets/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

`assets/main.css`

```
p {
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

I would like to call a function and get:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p {
        font-size: 24pt;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this from within the browser, or with Node, or from within a shell script? Do the css files always come from the same host? Do you want to load the page, and then (after loading) change the sourced stylesheet against the style tag (+ content), and then apply the styles again on the DOM? Or do you have a bunch of files that you want to batch-edit the way you indicated?

Comment: @knb From within the browser (content or background script on a Chrome Extension). The CSS files don't always come from the same host (but if it makes it easier, I can accept that we can ignore css files from different hosts). Don't need to change the styles. Not batch-editing, live from a Chrome Extension. I will edit this information into the original question.